# Keras model always predicts class with highest value counts

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

These are the value counts of the classes (left side is the class and right is the value count)  
4   472 
16      366 
1       334 
64      190
256      67
1024     12
4096      1

```
input_dim = len(df_cluster1_high.columns) - 1

dropout = 0.1
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_dim = input_dim , activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer='random_normal'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(Dense(7, activation = 'softmax'))
sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, momentum=0.9, decay=0.0001, nesterov=True)

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer='sgd', metrics = ['accuracy'] )

model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs = 10, batch_size = 2)

scores = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

The accuracy is around 30% cause it predicts 4 always.

Comment: can you write a precise question?

Comment: @BestDogeStackoverflow The model above only predicts the class with the most occurences. Here, the class "4" had the most occurences, and no matter what- the model only predicts "4".

Comment: Still the question is not clear, you need to train a model where `train_x` is the number of counts and `y_train` is the class? not sure if my understood is correctly